# CRM 2011 2015 2016 The 'Update' method does not support entities of type 'resource'

Tags: entity-framework, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone have idea how to update records in a CRM table named "ResourceBase" (Resource; ResourceSet) from a C# application.

We are able to update records in other entities, but on the "resource" table we receive the error message: 
`The 'Update' method does not support entities of type 'resource'`

We have to update field .

Maybe the problem is relationship between "ResourceBase" and other tables in CRM.

We can update this field from SQL Management Console at Onpremise version of CRM, but on Online version we haven't direct access to SQL database, so we need to do this through .NET app.

```
foreach (var row in getEntity.Entities)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(row["resourceid"]);

    if (row.Contains("isdisabled"))
    {
        row.Attributes["isdisabled"] = false;

        service.Update(getEntity.Entities[i]);
    }

    i++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resource is a complex data type that just looks up systemuser, team, equipment, resourcegroup entities. The `IsDisabled` attribute is derived from the entity sub type. So to `disable` a resource you would have to disable the subtype entity (e.g. disable the user).